# Why was my question put on hold, what can I do to improve it

Tags: discussion

Yesterday I asked this [question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/102362/gather-the-trash) which was very quickly put on hold.

As I rarely contribute here, I wouldn't have been surprised if my question has been closed as uninteresting, or too hard, or too easy, but the last thing I expected was the reason currently alleged, "unclear what you're asking". How anybody could find that full problem statement unclear is beyond me.

An upvoted comment indicates that my question makes perfect sense to several other users. My last comment asking for my critics to clarify what they found unclear got no answer at all.

Comment: I was not one of the close voters, but I can see why. If you directly incorporate ais523's suggestion regarding the balanced brackets, it makes the challenge significantly better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shouldn't have been closed as unclear. There are currently 4 reopen votes on it (one of them is mine). It should be reopened shortly.

Comment: I suppose that as a low-rep user I cannot see the reopen votes count

Comment: It should, because it's still unclear, but it's definitely best to explain the problems when voting to close as unclear.

Comment: @PeterTaylor It wasn't unclear at all to me. It could have been improved, but the specification was clear.